# How to fix 'The term 'firebase' is not recognized as function..' after installing firebase tools in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to set up my react app to use firebase cloud functions, after installing firebase tools in my react project, I encounter 'firebase not recognized' error when trying to run 'firebase init' or 'firebase login' command

I have included firebase as a path in my environment variables and restarted my PC multiple times, I still get the same error.

```
firebase : The term 'firebase' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase login
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (firebase:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

create a `firebaseConfig.js` file

```
import * as firebaseConfig from 'firebase';    
const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

firebaseConfig.initializeApp(config);

export default firebaseConfig;
```

then, instead of directly using `firebase`, use `firebaseConfig.js` file in your components,  
`import firebase from './firebaseConfig';`

Comment: this is not working for me. I already have a config file setup. Note; i need this because i'm trying to set up my application to use cloud functions